# How do I filter-out values in a list of dictionaries in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to exclude certain values from a list of dictionaries before I execute applymap function. I tried like so:

`data1 = pd.DataFrame(data).applymap(lambda x:x['A'] and ['P'] =='6.00')`

This gives me a dataframe with 'false' values throughout. It's obvious my logic is wrong.

(**See data in code**)

```
**Desired dataframe:**
        0      1
0    1.816  1.97 
1    1.856  1.925
2    0.00   0.00  ( zero values because 'P' doesn't meet criteria ie. 6.00 )
```

```
data = [[{'A': 1.816, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.97, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.0, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 1.856, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.925, 'G': 17, 'P': 6.00, 'T': 10}],
 [{'A': 2.25, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 9},
  {'A': 1.63, 'G': 17, 'P': 8.5, 'T': 10}]]
```

What can I try to achieve my objective most efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `pandas` instead of manipulating the dict. Read each list into a DataFrame with the correct constructor (`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`) and `concat` with keys. Then use `where` to mask the DataFrame, filling masked values with `NaN` and unstack.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x) for x in data], keys=range(len(data)))
#         A   G    P   T
#0 0  1.816  17  6.0   9
#  1  1.970  17  6.0  10
#1 0  1.856  17  6.0   9
#  1  1.925  17  6.0  10
#2 0  2.250  17  8.5   9
#  1  1.630  17  8.5  10

df['A'].where(df['P'].eq(6)).fillna(0).unstack()
```

---

```
       0      1
0  1.816  1.970
1  1.856  1.925
2  0.000  0.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I want to further execute this code snippet 
     .astype('str').values.tolist()).str.join("\n") to get eg. 1.816\n1.970 \etc . I get error :TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
Is there a way around?